Why the primary user can use the sudo command if he does not appear in the /etc/sudoers file?
When Ubuntu Desktop is being installed is requested create a primary user, let's named as tron
Once installed the OS is possible later do updates in the system through the sudo apt update command and related. The point is that the sudo command can be used
Through VirtualBox was installed Debian 12 as Desktop where is requested the root and primary users. I've confirmed that the primary user can not use the sudo command.
If is need it that the primary user can use the sudo command as in Ubuntu. So after to watch some videos in YouTube is mandatory add the user in the /etc/sudoers file as follows:
root    ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL
tron    ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL

Of course, the root account can be logged through the su -l root command
Just being curious I assumed that in Ubuntu in the /etc/sudoers file was already added throughout the OS installation the tron   ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL line but it is not the case.
Question

Why the primary user can use the sudo command if he does not appear in the /etc/sudoers file?


FYI:  You mention a comparison with Debian 12; don't forget Debian provides multiple installers like Ubuntu does, and if you use the live installer you can install Debian 12 and have it be identical to an Ubuntu install (ie. no root user and the added user will have sudo access).  You mention Ubuntu Desktop which has two installers currently available (you don't specify release) though I'd expect both those to act the same here (and like Debian calamares without root user being created).  This is a Ubuntu site however, not a Debian support site.

@muru I confirmed the primary user belongs to the sudo group through the id and groups commands, but it is very interesting because it does not happen in Fedora. Well I've created a question in its official Forum

@guiverc I just used for both OS the .iso file for Desktop - thus no live approach - remember I did do mention about VirtualBox, so both OS were installed. About Ubuntu it was with 20.04 LTS

Don't the RHEL family use the wheel group instead of sudo?

Ubuntu 20.04 LTS Desktop only offers a single ISO which used the ubiquity ISO (options vary on release; eg. 23.04 & 23.10 offered 2x ISOs using different installers), where as Debian 12 allows you to select at download time to use the calamares installer OR the debian installer (di) which differ... You select which installer you use at download time, eg. 24.04 ISOs are available which use ubuntu-desktop-installer, subiquity and calamares  (Ubuntu offered di too for 18.04 & earlier).  You are aware there are different ISOs download options in both Debian & Ubuntu aren't you?

@muru yes, that's correct. I confirmed
